# Adding multiple model outputs to merge tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, modelbuilder, merge, batch

I am using ModelBuilder to batch project multiple (site) specific geodatabases' contents then "Merge" like components into a single geodatabase.

I have up to eight FCs for each site (e.g. parcels, easements) and 21 sites. Say for parcels I have 21 parcels connected to the batch project.

How can I then add the "Merge tool" to the processing?

I can't actually add the 21 parcels since the reprojections do not yet exist.

Comment: Are you reprojecting within the model?  If so, you may source the in-memory output variables of the project tool as the input layers for the merge tool.

Comment: That sounds good. How?

Comment: In simplest terms try the following; 1. add in 21 project tools, 2. define the input and output for the 21 tools, 3. Add in the merge tool and source all the project tool outputs as the input for the merge tool.

Comment: Thank you. I had another advice source and went with iterating on feature class: project then append.

Comment: It sounds like you may have found your solution.  Assuming so, perhaps you or @artwork21 could write up a short (few sentences/steps) answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment one solution is:

1. Add in 21 project tools into MOdelBuilder
2. Define the input and output for the 21 tools
3. Add in the merge tool and source all the project tool outputs as the input for the merge tool

Or, the work around you noted:

1. Add in the feature class iterater and run fc through the Project tool
2. Reference output object of project tool into Append tool

Comment: @Chuckadillus both approaches will work, just wanted to say I think  the second approach would be the quickest model to knock out rather than dragging 21 tools into model builder and setting each one..